# Error when running "npm install --save express"

Tags: node.js, flutter, backend

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\node express> npm install --save express
npm WARN node-express@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN node-express@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json.3642225889
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json.3642225889' -> 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json.3642225889' -> 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json.3642225889' -> 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node express\node_modules\content-disposition\package.json'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\node express\\node_modules\\content-disposition\\package.json.3642225889',
npm ERR!     dest: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\node express\\node_modules\\content-disposition\\package.json'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\node express\\node_modules\\content-disposition\\package.json.3642225889',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\node express\\node_modules\\content-disposition\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'node express'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-21T17_33_56_539Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\node express>
```

Comment: did you do npm init first? if yes, try to move your folder 'node express' to c:/ and try to install again with the npm..(i had similar issue but because my user name included symobls, i don't know if its your case but its worth to try)

Comment: Classic Windows permission issues